# slow running computer

Tags: ram, 19.04, memory-usage

The computer slows down and the system monitor shows anywhere from 91% to 98% memory utilization and runs painfully slow. After a fresh reboot system monitor shows around 17% memory utilization. Gnome-shell increases in size from 133 Mb to upwards of 400 Mb. This happens even if the computer sits idle for any period of time.

with nothing running except firefox the memory has slowly crept up see below;

```
rick@rick-M52BC-M32BC:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7890        2369         625          44        4895        5179
Swap:         28804          35       28769

rick@rick-M52BC-M32BC:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7890        2493         466          71        4930        5028
Swap:         28804          35       28769
```

Here is where the memory is at 85% full. Same idle status

```
rick@rick-M52BC-M32BC:~$ free -m  
            total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available  
Mem:           7890        6470         206          54        1212          1070
Swap:         28804          69       28735
```

Here is the header from `top`:

```
top - 00:41:24 up 13:42,  1 user,  load average: 0.37, 0.59, 0.38
Tasks: 293 total,   1 running, 292 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.4 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7890.1 total,    255.4 free,   6382.5 used,   1252.3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  28805.0 total,  28735.5 free,     69.5 used.   1158.4 avail Mem
```

This will continue to creep up until all memory is used.

Comment: Could it be that you have disabled swapping to treat you SSD with care? 400 MB is a lot, but not soo much, that yould be perfectly fine, depending on what you do. Firefox sometimes requires 2 GB :)

Comment: I do not think it is just gnome-shell, there are other programs that eat memory as well. The biggest thing is that even on a fresh boot left idle the memory usage slowly goes up and eventually renders the computer to slow to operate without a reboot

Comment: Do top show what app(s) are using memory? you can install htop which sometimes works better.

Comment: my largest memory users are gnome-shell, plex dlna server and Xorg. also gnome-shell seems  take more memory the longer it runs

Comment: I added more detail in original message

Comment: *I may not be reading the question correctly, if you didn't already know:* The `free` section displays RAM that is not being used for anything, however Linux normally uses unused RAM to cache data, so the system runs faster. The `available` section is probably what you should be looking for, it doesn't include cached data. RAM being used for cache will automatically be cleared when required. Also, `free -h` has a nicer output.

Comment: I understand all that, but I think I have found the answer to my problem. I am going to answer the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the Linux will use memory to cache data was not the problem. I have finally found out the problem for the slow running computer. It was caused by the plex media server.

rick@rick-M52BC-M32BC:~$ service plexmediaserver stop

rick@rick-M52BC-M32BC:~$ service plexmediaserver start

dropped the memory usage down from 87% to 29% usage immediately.